# creating a list in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input list using which upon applying some if else logic while trying to save the output in a list. I'm when trying to check the type of it, found it to be "class list". I need to use this list and convert it to data frame in the next step so that i can have some terra data query written on top of it.
Also please note that upon writing the above piece of code in a single Jupiter window and when i go to the next Jupiter window and try query using the list index, i am always getting the last value in the list.
Need help in having the output set to a List, instead of Class List. also how to convert the list/Class list to a DataFrame?.

```
data = ['login', 'signup', 'account'] 

   

for i in range(len(data)):
    source = []
    if data[i] == 'login':
        table = "sales.login_table"
    elif data[i] == 'signup':
        table = "sales.signup_table"
    elif data[i] == 'account':
        table = 'sales.account'
    elif data[i] == 'addcc':
        table = "sales.addcc" 
    elif data[i] == 'consolidatedfunding':
        table = 'sales.consolidatedfunding'
    elif data[i] == 'deposit':
        table = 'sales.deposit'
    elif data[i] == 'holdsassessment':
        table = 'sales.holdsassessment'
    elif data[i] == 'onboardinggc':
        table = 'sales.onboardinggc'
    source.append(table)
    print(source)
    
print(source)

output:
['sales.login_table']
['sales.signup_table']
['sales.account']


print(type(source))
output :
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: I'm trying to store 3 table column into single dataframe by iterating in for loop. 

below is my query, but its always displaying only first table columns. 
`

q=[]
output=[]



for i in range(len(source)):
    q = "select * from {} sample 1".format(source[i])
    output.append(run_query(q))
    print(output)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `source = []` outside of for-loop, otherwise, in every  iteration it'll be declare as empty `list`.

```
source = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i] == 'login':
        table = "sales.login_table"
    elif data[i] == 'signup':
        table = "sales.signup_table"
    elif data[i] == 'account':
        table = 'sales.account'
    elif data[i] == 'addcc':
        table = "sales.addcc" 
    elif data[i] == 'consolidatedfunding':
        table = 'sales.consolidatedfunding'
    elif data[i] == 'deposit':
        table = 'sales.deposit'
    elif data[i] == 'holdsassessment':
        table = 'sales.holdsassessment'
    elif data[i] == 'onboardinggc':
        table = 'sales.onboardinggc'
    source.append(table)
print(source)
```

Comment: source = ['sales.login_table','sales.signup_table','sales.account']